# Prevent Infinispan from clustering

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I'm developing an application that works with a clustered Infinispan cache. 
For this I'm using `GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()` at the moment. 
When Infinispan is clustered, the initialization of the first cache always takes about 4 - 6 seconds for starting JGroups channel and joining the cluster. For development this is a bit tedious and unnecessary since I'm only working on one node. 
So my actual question is, if there is a way to prevent Infinispan from performing a cluster without changing my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the join_timeout attribute for the JGroups GMS protocol to 0 if not specified as a property:

```
<pbcast.GMS join_timeout="${jgroups.join.timeout:0}" view_bundling="true"/>
```